# Read multiple files and create one xml message in wso2 esb

Tags: xml, wso2, xslt-2.0, wso2-esb

we have a scenario in one of our integration project, where we have to read different XML files from a directory (ftp) and convert it to a single XML message using WSO2 ESB capabilities. Each XML file has different name and content I have searched a lot on Google but didn't find any relevant topic. Any help would be a great appreciation.
For example:

file1.xml

```
<dataroot>
  <data>
    <a>232</a>
  </data>
</dataroot>
```

file2.xml

```
<dataroot>
  <data2>
    <b>2434</b>
  </data2>
</dataroot>
```

Output:

```
<dataroot>
      <data>
        <a>232</a>
      </data>
      <data2>
        <b>3423</b>
      </data2>
</dataroot>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `VFS` transport, however note that the `VFS` transport needs to either **MOVE** or **DELETE** the original file. So it's best to apply the `VFS` processing on top of a proxy folder in between the FTP and WSO2 ESB if you don't want to perform those operations on the original FTP location itself.

Once you get that figured out you can use `XSLT mediator`/`Smooks Mediator` (if the files are large or high in number) on each file to collect the `data` elements. The `Enrich mediator` can be used to sequentially add the collected records to the `dataroot` parent.

1 - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+271%3A+File+Processing

2 - https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136056

3 - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Enrich+Mediator